# Riesz Lemma does not hold for $\epsilon=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Riesz Lemma:

> Let $Y$ be a closed proper vector subspace of a normed space $(X, \lVert. \rVert)$ and  let $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Then there exists $u_{\epsilon} \in X$ with $\lVert u_{\epsilon} \rVert  =1$ such that $\lVert u-y \rVert \geq \epsilon$ for all $y \in Y$

Now I saw a counterexample for $\epsilon=1$, which I don't really understand:

Define $X:=\{x \in C[0,1] : x(1)=0 \}$ with the norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{\infty} $ and consider $Y:=\{x\in X: \int_0^1 x(t)dt=0 \}$.
Let us assume that riesz lemma does hold for $\epsilon=1$ ,then there exists $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x-u\rVert_{\infty}$ for all $u \in Y$

Now defne $x_n(t):=1-t^n \in X$ and
$\lambda_n:=\frac{\int x(t)dt}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}$

Consider the sequence $u_n:=x-\lambda_n x_n$

Because of the way we chose $\lambda_n$ we know that $u_n$ is in $Y$. Thus $|\lambda_n|\geq 1$, which leads to a contradiction because $|\int_0^1 x| <1$

My Questions:
Since I only know that there exists $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x-u \rVert_{\infty} \geq 1$ I don't see why $u_n$ is in $Y$.
If $u_n$ is in $Y$ then:
$\int_0^1 u_n=0$ thus
$\int_0^1( x(t)- \frac{\int x(t) dt}{1- \frac{1}{n+1}}(1-t^n) dt)=0$

But the only thing I know about $x(t)$ is that $x(1)=0$ (since $x(t) \in X$). So why do we know that $u_n$ is in $Y$?

At the end of the proof it was mentioned that $|\int_0^1 x|<1$, where does this come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{1}u_n(t)dt=\int_0^1( x(t)- \frac{\int_0^{1} x(t) dt}{1- \frac{1}{n+1}}(1-t^n) dt)$$ $$=\int_0^{1}x(t)dt-\int_0^{1}x(t)dt \int_0^{1}(1-t^{n})dt/(1-\frac 1 {n+1}).$$ Just compute $\int_0^{1}(1-t^{n})dt$  to see that $\int_0^{1}u_n(t)dt=0$.

For the second question recall that $\|x\|=1$. So $|\int_0^{1}x(t)dt| \leq \int_0^{1} |x(t)|dt \leq \int_0^{1} 1dt=1$. If this were an equality then we would have $|x(t)|=1$ for all $t$ but $x(1)=0$. Hence, $|\int_0^{1} x(t)dt|<1$.

Comment: I dont't really see how this would solve it. $\int_0^1 (x(t)-\frac{\int x(t)dt}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}(1-t^n))dt=$
$\int_0^1 x(t)dt - \int_0^1 \int x(t)dt \frac{1-t^n}{1-\frac{1}{n+1
}} dt$

Now I did partiall integretion on $\int_0^1 \int x(t)dt (1-t^n) dt=[\int x(t)dt (t-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1})]_{t=0}^{t=1}-\int_0^1 x(t)(t-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1})dt$

This means I get:
$\int_0^1 (x(t)-\frac{\int x(t)dt}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}(1-t^n))dt=$
$\int_0^1 x(t)dt + \int_0^1 x(t)(t-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1})\frac{n+1}{n}dt$

Comment: I don't see why you get $\int_0^1( x(t)- \frac{\int x(t) dt}{1- \frac{1}{n+1}}(1-t^n) dt)=\int_0^{1}x(t)dt-\int_0^{1}x(t)dt \int_0^{1}(1-t^{n})dt/(1-\frac 1 {n+1})$

Comment: $\int x(t)dt$ is a constant. Pull it out before you compute the integral.

Comment: Why is $\int x(t) dt $ a constant? As far as I did understand it $\int x(t) dt$  is the antiderivative of $x(t)$, which is again a function of $t$, and since the "upper" integral is regardind $dt$....

Comment: Well, I think there is a typo in the proof. I think $\int x(t) dt$ should have been $\int_0^1 x(t) dt$

Comment: One last question: In the proof it is mentioned that from $|\lambda_n| \geq 1$ and $|\int_0^1 x(t) dt |<1$ we get a contradiction. I am not really able to see the contradiciton. Could you help me please see it?

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Since $|\lambda_n|\ geq 1$ and $\lambda_n=\frac{\int_0^1 x(t)dt}{1- \frac{1}{n+1}}$, I get $|\int_0^1 x(t) dt| \geq 1 $ which is a contradiction. Is this correct?